# Yaml github issue template showing raw file

Tags: github, yaml

I'm using github issue template in yaml. I copy/pasted the example code on github docs, and the select screen worked properly:

```
( ) <-----------------------------------+
     |Bug report          [Get started] | <- clicked
     |File a bug report                 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

but when I click the `[Get started]` button, the issue is showing me markdown editor with raw yaml text:

```
( ) <----------------------------------+
     |[Title                          ]|
     |[Write] [Preview]                |
     +---------------------------------+
     |+-------------------------------+|
     ||name: bug report               ||
     ||description: File a bug report ||
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     +=================================+
```

But when I try with exact same code on other repository -- which I made it for testing -- works fine.

Comment: Did you double check that the file is in the correct folder name as well as stored in the default branch for that repo (main/master or something else)?

Comment: And if the file has the correct extension?

Comment: @RobBos Yes. the file is named `기능-제안.yaml`(Hangul/Unicode) and It is in the directory `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE`. The directory is correct because it is created by the github issue template builder.

I tried changing the `.yaml` to `.yml` but it did not changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I found the problem:

##### the filename should not include unicode characters(non-ASCII).